# Guardar la posición de iteración de un diccionario para continuar luego

Tags: python, iteraciones

Tengo un conjunto de acciones que quiero realizar aleatoriamente. Una de las acciones itera sobre un diccionario. Quiero que cada vez que esta acción se llame, el diccionario itere a la próxima posición del diccionario y no a la primera.

Si necesitara solo un valor, podría usar una lista en lugar de un diccionario, guardar el índice de la lista afuera de la llamada de la función, y pasar el 
último indice de la lista a la función. Pero necesito ambos valores, la clave y el valor. Podría usar 2 listas, una que guarde la clave, otra que guarde el valor, guardar el indice afuera de la llamada de la función, pasar el último indice cada vez que se llama a acción 2, pero tal vez hay alguna forma más simple de hacerlo con diccionarios, guardando la posición que el diccionario estaba iterando de alguna forma, y no necesitaría usar 2 listas?

```
import random
import time

def action_one(): print "action 1"

def action_two():
    diccionarios_grupos_ids = {
    '580864492030176':'Rafaela Argentina',
    '314744565339924':'Ventas Rafaelinas',
    '976386572414848':'Ventas en Rafaela y Zona',
    '157271887802087':'Rafaela Vende',
    '77937415209':'Mas Poco Vendo',
    '400258686677963':'Clasificados Rafaela',
    '1708071822797472':'Vende Susana Roca Bella Italia Lehmann San Antonio Villa San Jose y Rafaela',
    '639823676133828':'L@s Loc@s de las ofertas sunchales!!!!!!',
    '686381434770519':'H&M Computacion',
    '1489889931229181':'RAFAELA Compra/Venta',
    '228598317265312':'Compra-Venta Rafaela',
    '406571412689579':'Alta Venta'}

    for key,value in diccionarios_grupos_ids.iteritems():
        print key,value
        # I want to iterate in the next position the next time action_two is called
        break

def action_three(): print "action 3"

lista_acciones = [action_one,action_two,action_three]

while True:

    tiempo_random = random.randint(1,3)

    time.sleep(tiempo_random)

    choice = random.choice(lista_acciones)
```

Comment: ¿Y si usas un [diccionario ordenado](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) y guardas el cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que usas Python 2.x e `iteritems` ya es un iterador, puedes valerte de él de una forma simple usando `next()`:

```
diccionarios_grupos_ids = {
    '580864492030176':'Rafaela Argentina',
    '314744565339924':'Ventas Rafaelinas',
    '976386572414848':'Ventas en Rafaela y Zona',
    '157271887802087':'Rafaela Vende',
    '77937415209':'Mas Poco Vendo',
    '400258686677963':'Clasificados Rafaela',
    '1708071822797472':'Vende Susana Roca Bella Italia Lehmann San Antonio Villa San Jose y Rafaela',
    '639823676133828':'L@s Loc@s de las ofertas sunchales!!!!!!',
    '686381434770519':'H&M Computacion',
    '1489889931229181':'RAFAELA Compra/Venta',
    '228598317265312':'Compra-Venta Rafaela',
    '406571412689579':'Alta Venta'}

iterador =  diccionarios_grupos_ids.iteritems()

def action_two():
    try:
        key, value = next(iterador)
        print key, value
        #...Resto de cosas a hacer en esta iteración
    except StopIteration:
        pass


action_two()
action_two()
```

Answer (score 3):

Aunque creo que sé lo que quieres hacer, no es necesario controlar externamente la iteración a través del diccionario, eso que que dices de *guardar fuera el último índice*. En python hay *"clausuras"* y, lo más importante, hay *"funciones generadoras"*.

En tu caso podrías usar *"diccionarios ordenados"*, pero creo que te sobra con un lista de tuplas:

```
def action_two_gen():
    grupos_ids = (
        ('580864492030176','Rafaela Argentina'),
        ('314744565339924','Ventas Rafaelinas'),
        ('976386572414848','Ventas en Rafaela y Zona'),
        ('157271887802087','Rafaela Vende'),
        ('77937415209','Mas Poco Vendo'),
        ('400258686677963','Clasificados Rafaela'),
        ('1708071822797472','Vende Susana Roca Bella Italia Lehmann San Antonio Villa San Jose y Rafaela'),
        ('639823676133828','L@s Loc@s de las ofertas sunchales!!!!!!'),
        ('686381434770519','H&M Computacion'),
        ('1489889931229181','RAFAELA Compra/Venta'),
        ('228598317265312','Compra-Venta Rafaela'),
        ('406571412689579','Alta Venta'),
    )
    for (key, value) in grupos_ids:
        yield (key, value)

it = action_two_gen()

def action_two():
    global it

    (key, value) = next(it, (None, None))
    print (key, value)

action_two()
action_two()
```

Como es muy recomendable evitar las variables globales, una forma de elegante de hacer lo mismo es encapsular todo en una clase *"callable"*:

```
grupos_ids = (
    ('580864492030176','Rafaela Argentina'),
    ('314744565339924','Ventas Rafaelinas'),
    ('976386572414848','Ventas en Rafaela y Zona'),
    ('157271887802087','Rafaela Vende'),
    ('77937415209','Mas Poco Vendo'),
    ('400258686677963','Clasificados Rafaela'),
    ('1708071822797472','Vende Susana Roca Bella Italia Lehmann San Antonio Villa San Jose y Rafaela'),
    ('639823676133828','L@s Loc@s de las ofertas sunchales!!!!!!'),
    ('686381434770519','H&M Computacion'),
    ('1489889931229181','RAFAELA Compra/Venta'),
    ('228598317265312','Compra-Venta Rafaela'),
    ('406571412689579','Alta Venta'),
)

class Action_Two(object):
    def __init__(self, ids):
        self.gen = iter(ids)
    def __call__(self):
        (key, value) = next(self.gen, (None, None))
        print (key, value)

action_two = Action_Two(grupos_ids)
action_two()
action_two()
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta solución es un poco menos elegante que las anteriores, pero permite iterar indefinidamente, el uso del `OrderedDict` es simplemente para verificar que se este recorriendo adecuadamente todos los items, podría usarse un diccionario común o incluso una lista.

```
import random
import time
from collections import OrderedDict

def action_one(): print "action 1"

def action_two():
    action_two.lastkey = iterate(diccionarios_grupos_ids ,action_two.lastkey )

def iterate(mydict, iterator):
    iterator = iterator or mydict.iteritems()
    try:
        while True:
            k,v = iterator.next()
            print k,v
            return iterator

    except StopIteration:
        return None

def action_three(): print "action 3"

action_two.lastkey = None
lista = [
          ('580864492030176','Rafaela Argentina'),
          ('314744565339924','Ventas Rafaelinas'),
          ('976386572414848','Ventas en Rafaela y Zona'),
          ('157271887802087','Rafaela Vende'),
          ('77937415209','Mas Poco Vendo'),
          ('400258686677963','Clasificados Rafaela'),
          ('1708071822797472','Vende Susana Roca Bella Italia Lehmann San Antonio Villa San Jose y Rafaela'),
          ('639823676133828','L@s Loc@s de las ofertas sunchales!!!!!!'),
          ('686381434770519','H&M Computacion'),
          ('1489889931229181','RAFAELA Compra/Venta'),
          ('228598317265312','Compra-Venta Rafaela'),
          ('406571412689579','Alta Venta')
]

diccionarios_grupos_ids  = OrderedDict(lista)
lista_acciones = [action_one,action_two,action_three]
action_two.lastkey = None

while True:
    tiempo_random = random.randint(1,3)
    time.sleep(tiempo_random)
    choice = random.choice(lista_acciones)()
```

"Robando" la idea de @ChemaCortes, que me gustó mucho, y encapsulando todo, se puede llegar a una clase que por un lado obtenga los avisos y por otro permita una iteración infinita sobre ellos. Algo así:

```
class Action_Two(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.avisos = self.get_avisos()
        self.gen = iter(self.avisos)

    def get_avisos(self):
      return (
                ('580864492030176','Rafaela Argentina'),
                ('314744565339924','Ventas Rafaelinas'),
                ('976386572414848','Ventas en Rafaela y Zona'),
                ('157271887802087','Rafaela Vende'),
                ('77937415209','Mas Poco Vendo'),
                ('400258686677963','Clasificados Rafaela'),
                ('1708071822797472','Vende Susana Roca Bella Italia Lehmann San Antonio Villa San Jose y Rafaela'),
                ('639823676133828','L@s Loc@s de las ofertas sunchales!!!!!!'),
                ('686381434770519','H&M Computacion'),
                ('1489889931229181','RAFAELA Compra/Venta'),
                ('228598317265312','Compra-Venta Rafaela'),
                ('406571412689579','Alta Venta'),
            )

    def __call__(self):
        try:
          (key, value) = next(self.gen)

        except StopIteration:
          self.gen = iter(self.avisos)
          (key, value) = next(self.gen)

        print (key, value)


action_two = Action_Two()
while True:
    action_two()
```